# NSTimer triggered twice after switching view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, nsnotification

I'm trying to keep accurate counting and display of a countdown timer between switching view controllers. In order to do so, I added NSNotifications as mentioned in this question: [Timer Label not updated after switching views (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993584/timer-label-not-updated-after-switching-views-swift)

The problem is that the timer will be decremented twice after switching back from the other view controller.
This issue seems to be unrelated to the notifications, as the same problem occurs without them, it only becomes apparent after restarting the timer as it isn't updated automatically when reaching the view controller.

I really don't find the cause of this, any help much appreciated!

I've set up this sample code. There's another view controller added to the original one in Main.storyboard, there is one switch and one label displaying the timer added to it. The original view controller only contains one bar button item to trigger the segue to the second view controller.

```
import Foundation

final class DataModel: NSObject {

  static let shared = DataModel()

  var isSleepTimerOn = false
  var timerTime: NSTimeInterval = 100.0

}

// The second view controller.

import UIKit

class TimerViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var timerSwitch: UISwitch!

  var timer: NSTimer?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timerSwitch.on = DataModel.shared.isSleepTimerOn
    timerLabel.text = String(DataModel.shared.timerTime)

    let selector = #selector(setTimerLabel), name = "setTimerLabel"
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: selector, name: name, object: nil)
  }

  @IBAction func switchToggled(sender: AnyObject) {
    DataModel.shared.isSleepTimerOn = timerSwitch.on

    switch timerSwitch.on {
    case true:
      startTimer()
    case false:
      stopTimer()
    }
  }

  func startTimer() {
    let selector = #selector(decrementTimer)
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: selector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer!, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
  }

  func decrementTimer() {
    DataModel.shared.timerTime -= 1
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("setTimerLabel", object: nil)

    setTimerLabel()
  }

  func setTimerLabel() {
    timerLabel.text = String(DataModel.shared.timerTime)
  }

  func stopTimer() {
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil

    DataModel.shared.timerTime = 100.0
    timerLabel.text = String(DataModel.shared.timerTime)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "setTimerLabel", object: nil)
  }

}
```

EDIT: Solution: move the timer from the view controller class to the DataModel singleton, so there would be only one timer.

Comment: I recently built a timer that I wanted to persist no matter what. I made a string of an NSDate that I stored in CoreData when I started the timer. Then I would retrieve that string with a getter turning it back into an NSDate. I then would make a time interval between that date and the current date. Last, I would check if that the timer's total length - the time interval I just made was > 0. If that was the case I restarted the timer with whatever amount it was > 0 until it's completion before the user could see the view it was on. Using this method will guarantee your time left is accurate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion Sethmr, I will definitely try that approach next time, it kinda seems like overkill in my situation where I basically just need a sleep timer. I'd still like to find the bug in the code above, so if anyone knows...!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, new morning, fresh brain, had another look at the code and the problem was clear: I was initiating a new timer every time I switched to the view controller, so when stopping the timer, it wouldn't stop the previous one. Since there should be only one timer I moved it from the view controller class to the DataModel, which is a singleton.